# Showing and hiding the angular material toolbar on an interval?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

I'm attempting to test the CSS animation for showing and hiding the angular material toolbar in [this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/show-hide-toolbar?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Within the app component the `hide` property is switched on an interval like this:

```
  hide:boolean = false
  show() {
    this.hide = !this.hide;
    console.log(`Hide? ${this.hide}`)
  }
  constructor() {
    this.show.bind(this)
    setInterval(this.show, 2000)
  }
```

The CSS is declared like this on the `mat-toolbar`:

```
<mat-toolbar [ngClass]="hide ? 'hideToolbar' : 'showToolbar'"
             class="hideShowToolbar"><h2>Material Baseline</h2>
</mat-toolbar>
```

The `ngClass` directive does not toggl between `hideToolbar` and `showToolbar`.  Thoughts?

Also tried an `Observable` variation:

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/show-hide-toolbar-observable?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be here you will able to use `rxjs` library `interval` like below in `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { interval } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  hide:boolean = false
  secondsCounter = interval(2000);
  show() {
    this.hide = !this.hide;
    console.log(`Hide? ${this.hide}`)
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.secondsCounter.subscribe(()=>{
      this.show();
    })
  }
}
```

Working [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/show-hide-toolbar-86fi9b?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

In above code we're subscribing to empty response by rxjs observable in `ngOnInit()`. Reactivex/Rxjs is really useful when it comes to perform actions reactively and it has been one of the main focus of angular developer team at google to attract community towards its powers.

Useful sources to know more about `rxjs` : 
https://angular.io/guide/rx-library 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aYurQaN3RoE (very intuitive talk/must watch)

Comment: Awesome - Any idea why the original demo does not work.  They seem to be doing the same thing?

Comment: I have used the interval  from 'rxjs'

Comment: Hmmm ... I think it's because in your case we don't bind `this` to `show`.

Comment: I think Angular cannot pick up calls to the `bind` version of show.

Comment: hmm. yes correct, seems to be angular change detection mechanism could not able to pick up it

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this:

```
export class DemoComponent implements OnInit{
  public hidden: boolean;

  ngOnInit() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.hidden = ! this.hidden;
    }, 2000);
  }
}
```

The toggle a `hidden` class in the template:

```
<mat-toolbar [class.hidden]="hidden" class="hideShowToolbar">
<h2>Material Baseline</h2>
</mat-toolbar>
```

Here is a sample transition that will animate the toolbar in from the right:

```
mat-toolbar{
  position: fixed;
  top:10px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 420px;
  transition:right .25s linear;
  &.hidden{
    right: -420px;
  }
}
```

Comment: IIUC we are not switching between the two classes `hideToolbar` and `showToolbar` in this case?

Comment: I personally prefer to toggle a single class for brevity

Comment: IIUC I think we loose the CSS tranform in this case if we do that ...?

Comment: you can still animate the transition, i will update my answer with the CSS

Comment: Cool - Nice to see a variation.